# Empty cells in SSRS giving random values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am building a report grouped by week horizontal and grouped by month vertical but some month start in the middle of the week and in this case SSRS gets random values and put them on the days that don't have dates. how can I get rid of this?

Example here [image: https://imgur.com/a/f1t69KM]

Comment: Without the definition of your report, and a sample dataset, this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: I don't know that I understand the grouping, but I'm guessing this is in the date format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.  Based on that, if Wednesday is May 1st, then it's not exactly random for the following Monday to be the 6th as Saturday and Sunday would be `04/05/2019` and `05/05/2019`, respectively.  The week is wrapping to the next valid date for Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: I have data on the second week but SSRS brought the date from the second week and put them on the first week. I don't want Monday and Tuesday on the first week to have any date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way the report is build should be changed to be able to see the correct data. i did change it from table to a matrix and put an if statement to fill the cells that has no dates.

Thanks